# how could i create grouped listbox in WPF .net 6 with multi items and custom design in group header

Tags: .net, wpf

i tried already every thing i could think about , and searched a lot for a slution

thats my current XMAL PART of the group header i'm trying to figgure

```
<ListBox.GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle >


        <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>

            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="GrpDate" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14" Text="{Binding Name}" TextAlignment="Right" Grid.Row="0"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="GrpNote" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14" Text="{Binding Note }" TextAlignment="Right" Grid.Row="1"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="GrpNote1" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14" Text="{Binding orderid }" TextAlignment="Right" Grid.Row="1"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>


    </GroupStyle>
</ListBox.GroupStyle>
```

my data is bind to SQL server, and i tried using collection views

Comment: What exactly is your question? What do you want to accomplish, what have you tried, what happens and what do you expect to happen when you run your application?

Comment: would like to have multipile data displaying in the group header
for example: OrderID, OrderDate, OrderDecription, in group header
items, quantity, price 
in the detail part

Comment: Does the grouping work?

Comment: yes but only the name field showing the field was grouped on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DataContext` of a `GroupItem` has an `Items` property that contains all grouped items so you should be able to bind to the `Note` and `orderid` properties of an item in the group like this:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="GrpDate" ... Text="{Binding Name}" />
<TextBlock x:Name="GrpNote" ... Text="{Binding Items[0].Note }" />
<TextBlock x:Name="GrpNote1" ... Text="{Binding Items[0].orderid }" />
```

Comment: wow amazing 
Thanks a lot, i send already a lot of hours on that